# Returning MultipartFormDataContent as part of a HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return a `MultipartFormDataContent`from an endpoint, but I'm having trouble reading the content from the client side. This is what my endpoint looks like:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
    var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var myDto = new MyDto { Name = "John", Age = 30 };
    var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    formDataContent.Add(jsonContent, "myDto");

    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\data.tar"));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    formDataContent.Add(fileContent, "file", "data.tar");

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = formDataContent;

    return response;
}
```

On the client side:

```
{
     using var client = new HttpClient();

     var backendRespons2 = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5094/message/test");

     var contentTypeMediaType = backendRespons2.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

     var content = await backendRespons2.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

}
```

The `contentTypeMediaType` is set to application/json and `ReadAsMultipartAsync()` throws an exception:

> Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content
> type header starting with 'multipart/

What am I doing wrong here?